# Traking / Debugging issues on a LIVE web site

Tags: web-services

We work for a website and regularly we face some issues in LIVE. Hence we need to come up with an concept of easily being notified of issues occurring in LIVE rather after it gets escalated to sever level.

Say, we want to get notify / alerted of any failures that happens in LIVE for a flow - so how do we track these? Is there a framework that does so or there is an specific mechanism to achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what technologies you are using.

Comment: Mostly C++ to serve backend services with a set of web pages hosted via Apache

Comment: Just how exactly google / amazon and other website have their LIVE tracking system?

Comment: what kinda issues u are facing like some coding bug which u r nt able to find OR some deployment problem to server OR etc....

Comment: No coding .. could be anything - code issue (due to flow variable values - say in our DB a variable value is NULL which it should not be)/ user leaving site / user facing issues / user experience etc.

Answer (score 0):

u can use some application development platforms like **visual basic**, **netbeans**, **eclipse** for development of application which will help you to debug the complete code by using method *breakpoints* in case it is nt running as expected.

Comment: Well this is about tracking issues in LIVE (after code push) - not while development